# How can i run my automation script automatically in every 1 hours using yml file for jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

How can i run my automation script automatically in every 1 hours using yml file for jenkins pipeline.

I have tried this code but exactly no idea how to achieve.

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        label BMTC AVLS
    }
        triggers{
             cron('0 * * * *')
        }
    stages{
        stage('Test') {
            script{
                echo "File open for avls"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
               always {
                       echo 'This will always run'
                      }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins supports several aliases: `@hourly, @daily, @weekly, @monthly, @midnight`

So this should work:

```
triggers {
  cron '@hourly'
}
```

You can also use `0 * * * *` if you want it to be run every hour at the same minute (0) or `H * * * *` if you want it hourly but you don´t mind if it runs at minute 0 or 59. `@hourly` is just an alias for `H * * * *`

There are plenty of sites where you can test your cron expressions, i.e.:

- https://crontab.guru/
- https://crontab.cronhub.io/